# cache sweeper not working for custom method Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using fragment caching in my rails 4 project. I have cities controller and city_sweeper

```
cities_controller.rb
   cache_sweeper :city_sweeper, :only => [:update, :destroy]
   .
   .
   def update_featured
    @city = City.unscoped.find(params[:id])
    if params[:featured]
      @city.update_attribute(:featured, params[:featured])
    end
    render :text => "success:
   end
   .
end
```

and in my city_sweeper.rb I have this code

```
class CitySweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
 observe City

 def after_update(city)
  expire_cache(city)
 end

 def after_destroy(city)
  expire_cache(city)
 end

 def after_update_featured(city)
  expire_cache(city)
 end

 def expire_cache(city)
  expire_fragment "city_index_#{city.id}"   
 end
end
```

its working fine with CRUD operation, but its not working for my custom method.its calling my sweeper.rb , but I am not getting city object there. I am getting this error:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `expire_fragment' for #<CitySweeper:0xab9f1e0 @controller=nil>):
```

Comment: You need to use like `expire_fragment(:controller => 'cities', :action => 'index', 
  :action_suffix => 'all_cities)`

Comment: my view part => - if @cities.present?
                            - @cities.each do |city|
                                - cache "city_index_#{city.id}", skip_digest: true do

Answer (score 0):

You can expire the `fragment cache` using this

**UPDATE**

```
if @cities.present?
  @cities.each do |city|
    cache(action: 'recent_update',key: "city_index_#{city.id}", skip_digest: true) do
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

In Sweeper

```
class CitySweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe City

  .....
  def expire_cache(city)  
    expire_fragment(controller: 'cities', action: 'recent_update',key: "city_index_#{city.id}")
  end
end
```

Comment: but when I am calling my custom method that is update_feature then city object is getting updated through update_attribute , at that time its not expiring fragment

Comment: I am getting this error : NoMethodError: undefined method `expire_fragment' for #<CitySweeper:0xd03e0a0 @controller=nil>
from /home/hemant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rails-observers-0.1.2/lib/rails/observers/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb:105:in `method_missing'